# Show that $\oint (\vec{c} \cdot \vec{r} )d\vec{l} = \vec{a} \times \vec{c}$

Tags: derivatives, vector-spaces, vectors, vector-analysis

[image]

I need to prove part c). This is what I've tried (using Stokes Theorem):

$$\nabla \times \vec{c}T = T(\nabla \times \vec{c}) - \vec{c} \times (\nabla T)$$
$$=(\vec{c} \cdot \vec{r})(\nabla \times \vec{c})- \vec{c} \times (\nabla (\vec{c} \cdot \vec{r}))$$

But I'm stuck. Any tips?

Comment: Is $\vec c$ a constant vector?

Comment: @Dr.MV it is not. It's given as a vector function

Comment: I doubt that it is a function of $\vec r$ since it appears in the final result outside of the integral.